# Express JS static file with Angular $locationProvider.html5Mode (express.static)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I have a angular app using Express JS server side. I have removed the angular # (hashbangs) with the angular `$locationProvider.html5Mode` and set the base in the header of the html. Its all working fine until I reload the page when i'm not on the root. For instance if i am at http://myapp.com/anypath and reload my static files get the 'anypath' added in i.e. http://myapp.com/anypath/assets/css/app.css rather then http://myapp.com/assets/css/app.css

Here is my `index.js` my Express server is using

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app'));

app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname +'/app' });
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

I have looked at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode and know this should answer my issue but im a noobs and cant get it to work :(

File Structure:

```
root >
    index.js
    node_modules
    app >
        assets >
             css
             images
        bower_components
        src >
            js
            views
```

I think its to do with the express.static but any help would be great!

Cheers

Comment: Make sure the path to your assets in your html start with `/` like `"/assets/css/whatever.css"`

Comment: @Molda thanks you were right... though it was a bigger problem then it was. Just needed to check my `index.html` more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to check my css link more carefully,  '/' was missing from the front.